# iOS: clear/reset all controls in different forms

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have several screens - like Register, Search, Login, etc.
All have `UITextView`, `UIPickerView`, `UITableView`- on whose `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` different ViewControllers are pushed and values are fetched from those ViewControllers.

All the screens have reset button. On reset click, all controls should be filled with blank or default values.

Instead of coding it on each ViewController to clear all controls, is there a way to fetch all controls from a form and and empty all controls using `category` for View class?

How do I do this?

Comment: I'd be curious whether you've attempted code to parse all the subviews of a VC's view, see if they're a UIControl type, and do this reset.   If you have a simple subset of UIControls, it should be fairly straightforward.  But looking at what you attempt might suggest better answers.

Comment: @stevesliva I just parsed UIView and checked if the control type is UITextView or UITextField, and cleared them. I created a category for this and for tableView I wrote a custom method as that was a specific need.

Comment: Sounds like what I'd do, too.  Unfortunately, UIControl doesn't have a default value to reset to, so you have to handle all UIControl subclasses individually.   I did want to clarify that you're looking for a slicker way to do this.